# Acceso denegado a la ruta Storage - Permisos Android

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin, permisos

Tengo un método que descarga una imagen por medio de una URL en el almacenamiento del teléfono y estoy teniendo un error que interpreto como que no tengo permisos de guardar la imagen.

Lo raro es que le solicito permiso al cliente antes de hacerlo, y si me deja pasar es porque está aprobado.

De hecho, en el emulador dónde lo estoy probando en este momento ni siquiera me muestra la petición porque desde la primera vez que se ejecuta la app la solicito.

Pero no sé que está ocurriendo.

Error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path
> /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/jdkakfhmak.jpg is denied

Solicitud de permiso para ejecutar evento:

```
RequestPermissions(PermisosParaPublicarImagenes, PermisosHabilitados);
```

Array de permisos:

```
readonly string[] PermisosParaPublicarImagenes =
        {
            Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage,
            Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage
        };
```

Al obtener permisos:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            if (grantResults[0] == 0 && grantResults[1] == 0)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Compartiendo Sinopsis...", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                CompartirEn(gLogo, Titulo, Contenido);
            }
        }
```

Evento ejecutado despues de obtener los permisos y en donde da el error:

```
public async Task CompartirEn(string URL, string Titulo, string ContenidoaCompartir, string Tipo = "")
        {
            try
            {

                //Descargar imagen a enviar:
                string localPath = "";

                var webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[e.Result.Length];
                    bytes = e.Result; // get the downloaded data
                    string documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;

                    var partedURL = URL.Split('/');
                    string localFilename = partedURL[partedURL.Length - 1];
                    localFilename = "MyApp" + localFilename;
                    localPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
                    localPath2 = localPath.ToString();
                    File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, bytes); // *******AQUI DA EL ERROR************

                    MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(Application.Context, new string[] { localPath }, null, null);
                };
                ...

                //Listo. //Mostrar apps para compartir...

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                //Mostrar error
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Este error es provocado porque no puedes escribir en la ubicación que indica:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path
> /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/jdkakfhmak.jpg is denied

Este se debe a que si estás compilando tu proyecto con [Android 10](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#ApiLevels) como target o  superior, el lugar donde se guardaran los archivos y los cuales podrás acceder desde tu aplicación sería:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/
```

de hecho el método [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) es obsoleto desde [Android 10](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#ApiLevels), ahora debes usar [**getExternalFilesDir()**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.context.getexternalfilesdir?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12)